# How to create label-like explanatory text fields in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# form. I want to write some explanations. I tried RichTextBox and multi-line TextBox. I make them read-only, changed cursor to default in order to get the indicated part in the image below but I cannot prevent selection. The format I want is like Label: you cannot select text, cursor is not IBeam etc. However label is very limited, I am not able to get multi-line. How can I create such explanation part in winforms as shown with a red arrow below?

[example image http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg191/scaled.php?server=191&filename=csharpbox.jpg&res=medium](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg191/scaled.php?server=191&filename=csharpbox.jpg&res=medium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a Label similar to that one, just disable AutoSize, the text will wrap as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Label`, just change `AutoSize` to false.

```
Label l = new Label();
l.AutoSize = false;
l.Text = "Hello\nWorld";
```

Comment: thank you, I checked properties but skipped AutoSize I think... One more thing: how can I add "\n" in Text property? Is it only possible programatically?

Comment: You can do it programatically or click the arrow on the side, then just type.

Comment: Can I style text that I write? Text color, bold, italic etc.

Comment: You can't format specific parts of the `Label` but you can set the text color and font for the whole `Label` using `Label.Font` and `Label.ForeColor`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to insert a lot of text in a label. You could replace the label with a textbox and play with its display properties to make it look like a label. For example, remove the border, make the background color transparent.

If you still want to use a label maybe you should check this [solution](http://www.techyv.com/questions/how-wrap-text-label-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a tooltip with the explanation?